# Memory held by WinRT sample is not released

Tags: c#, image, memory, memory-leaks, windows-runtime

I am trying to release the memory held by images when removing the images from the sample. I have attached a [sample](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/DownloadFile?downloadLink=513dcec7-c748-449b-9567-5f128a106b4c%3BMemoryReleaseTest.zip) to illustrate this issue.

Steps to reproduce this issue:

Step 1: Run the sample, you will note that about 21 mb will be consumed by the sample

Step 2: Click on AddCtrl button, about 54 mb will be consumed

Step 3: Click on RemoveCtrl button, memory consumed is not released.

I posted this in a Microsoft's forum, they say this to be issue with the Operating System. Can someone point me out to any workaround available to release the memory being held.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage Collection in .NET often doesn't release memory right away when objects are no longer referenced, but in your case there's more to it. In the sample, your code adds images by adding them to a StackPanel, but the remove button tries to clear them by removing the ScrollViewer, which is the parent of the StackPanel, from its parent Grid. This is the original code:

```
private void btnRemoveControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    parentGrid.Children.Remove(scrollViewer);
}
```

I thought this was an odd way to do it, so I changed the code to simply remove the images from the StackPanel where they were added:

```
private void btnRemoveControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    stackPanel.Children.Clear();
}
```

This actually resulted in much of the memory being freed immediately upon the Remove button being clicked. In my tests, clicking Add would bump the memory up to 50 MB, and clicking Remove with this new code would make it drop to 29 MB.

But remember, .NET isn't super aggressive about reclaiming memory unless it's under pressure. So, I added another line:

```
private void btnRemoveControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    stackPanel.Children.Clear();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

With that code, clicking Remove drops the memory from 50 MB to 12 MB in my test.

However, putting GC.Collect() calls in your code is generally a really bad idea and is terrible for performance, because it forces an immediate GC on all generations. It's best to just let .NET clean up the memory when it thinks it needs to. I only added that line to prove whether GC can free up the rest of the memory if it needs to.

What you do need to do is make sure you're not holding onto references for objects you no longer need, so that .NET can clean up memory when it gets around to it. In your original code, I believe that ScrollViewer is still being referenced somewhere, perhaps because it's defined in the XAML. The ScrollViewer holds a reference to the StackPanel, which holds references to the images, and as a result none of them can be garbage collected. But if you just remove the images, which is what you're really trying to free from memory, it works.